# Как задеплоить Django приложение(Wagtail) на хостинг с DEBUG==FALSE

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, хостинг, развертывание

борюсь с данной проблемой вторые сутки :(
Проблема заключается в том что при отключение дебаг режима в setting на всех страницах ошибка. Абсолютно голое приложение - wagtail. при Debug==True все абсолютно в порядке, но кастомная 404 от wagtail(пишу wagtail в уме сайт на django) не загружается.

Сначала думал, что это стандартная ошибка когда не загружаюсь static, но понял(путем применения библиотек WhiteNoise(двух версий 2.0.6 и последней), django.static и еще нескольких вариантов) что вряд ли так как в статиках только css и js а не загружается даже html.  Потом подумал что ошибка в wsgi(у wsgi специальное название специально для reg.ru) файле, но ошибок вроде нет. Пробовал переустанавливать полностью wagtail

[image]

passenger_wsgi.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/u1664323/data/www/name.ru/name')
sys.path.insert(1, '/var/www/u1664323/data/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'name.settings.production'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.static import serve 

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    path('search/', search_views.search, name='search'),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:

    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),

    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    path("pages/", include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

Дальше разделение setting на несколько частей(это сделал wagtail)

base.py

```
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'search',

    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',

    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'name.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'name.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'USER': 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "name"

WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
    }
}

BASE_URL = 'http://name.ru'
```

production.py

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['name.ru','www.name.ru'] 

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

в консоле на сайте: GET http://name.ru/admin/ 502 (Bad Gateway)
Знаю что вопрос очень противный и мало кто любит отвечать на такие длинные вопросы, но все равно очень прошу помочь(ну или хотя бы подсказать куда копать), за два дня все перепробовал идеи просто кончились :(

Comment: Суть не в длине вопроса, а в его конкретике. Так что за ошибка-то? Что выводится в логах или при старте процесса из терминала?

Answer (score 0):

У Django версия 4.1 и выше STORAGE записывается в таком виде.

```
STORAGES = {
    # ...
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    },
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, вопрос был написан задолго до выхода 4.1, а во-вторых, STORAGES появился только в Django 4.2, а в 4.1 всё по-старому